# Parsing The Package error in Oreo 8.0

Tags: android, release, signed, android-8.0-oreo

I generated a signed apk using my release keystore and shared the apk via mail. When I downloaded the apk from the mail in an Android Oreo 8.0 device, I got the dialog "There Was A Problem Parsing The Package". My compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion is 27 and minSdkVersion is 15. The apk works on all devices except on Android Oreo 8.0 device. Also, I have ran the apk on a 8.0 emulator and it works fine.

Can you please let me know how to fix this issue so that the apk is installing on an Android Oreo 8.0 version device too?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

I would say the biggest difference in manually installing APK files is the recent substitution of the (global) "Allow apps from Unknown Sources" security setting
for the new app as a "trusted source" method

Quoting from [link](http://androidflagship.com/28497-enable-install-from-unknown-sources-on-android-oreo):

> First of all, enter into Settings;
>
> Click on the new "*Apps and Notifications*" menu;
>
> Go to *Special Access* at the bottom;
>
> Then, proceed to *Install other apps* which is also towards the bottom;
>
> Click on the app you want to allow or block;
>
> Tap on the switch next to Trust app from this source; // --> this is the app you're using to install the apk (ie. file explorer, or Chrome, etc)
>
> After that, go back to your app, and tap on the APK
> file to install it.
>
> On File manager app, it’s easy, but in browsers,
> go to downloads section and then tap on APK file to begin its
> installation.

This is not the only source of apk parsing errors, sometimes the file is corrupted / the download process corrupted the file.

Perhaps unlikely but also a possible cause of that error is when someone purposefully altered the apk after it being built/signed. Digital signature verification would not match.

So maybe resend the file and download it again if the above steps are not enough.

Hope this helps ;)